# Custom icon to a link in USB Drive with relative path

Tags: hyperlink, relative-path, usb-drive, desktop.ini, custom-icons

I have to distribute a project in several USB Drives. Inside them there's a folder containing the entire project (which will be made hidden) and a link to it with a custom icon applied.

The problem is that if I insert the USB Drive in another PC, the name of the drive changes (D , E , F ..) and the custom icon is no longer applied to the link, as the initial path is changed.

So I tried to create a desktop.ini file with inside:
`[.ShellClassInfo] IconResource=..\icon.ico,0`

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to apply the icon to the link so it works on different pc's?

Answer (score 0):

If the icon.ico file is directly inside the folder, then you don't need `..\`
It should be like this

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=icon.ico,0
```